# munu with jQuery but could not highlighte item as actived

Tags: jquery, menu

The code works as menu and submenu within href=#, 
but could not work **href=domain.com/index/id/12**

------------ **JS**

```
  $(function(){
    $('.menu1 a').each(function(i){
        if($(this).attr('class')=='this'||$(this).attr('class')=='this hover'){
            $('.menu2').eq(i).show();
        }
        $(this).click(function(){ /*mousemove*/
            $('.menu1 a').removeClass('this'); 
            $(this).addClass('this');           
            $('.menu2').hide();
            $('.menu2').eq(i).show();
            });

    });
});
```

---------- **Menu**

```
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu1">
            <a class="this" href="javascript:;">about</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">contact</a>
            <a href="www.domain.com/index/id/12">help</a> (does not highlighted if 

selected)
            <a href="javascript:;">other</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu2">
            <a href="www.domain.com/index/product">ASP</a> (submenu same as above)
            <a href="javascript:;">PHP</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">CGI</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu2">
            <a href="javascript:;">sql</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">CSS</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">efg</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">google</a>
            <a href="javascript:;">something</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

----------**CSS**

```
    .menu1{height:30px;background:#CCCCCC;} /*#1B75C4*/
    .menu1 a{display:inline;float:left;height:30px;line-height:30px;color:#fff;margin:0 

5px;padding:0 5px;}
    .menu1 a:hover,.menu1 a.this,.menu1 a.hover{background:#fff; color:#333;}

    .menu2{height:30px;display:none;}
    .menu2 a{display:inline;float:left;height:30px;line-height:30px;margin:0 

5px;padding:0 5px;}
    .menu2 a:hover{color:#1B75C4;}
```

Thanks for any help.

------------- Thanks for any help

Comment: Thanks Felix it works, but could not set URL on Browser bar where to point method or pages from PHP

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)** to prevent default click action of your anchor:

```
$(this).click(function (e) { /*mousemove*/
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu1 a').removeClass('this');
    $(this).addClass('this');
    $('.menu2').hide();
    $('.menu2').eq(i).show();
});
```